# Cannot invoke initializer for Phone data with an argument list of type '(phoneName: String)'

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, model-view-controller

I am making a table view app for iPhone showcase with image price and a
name and I am getting an error on line 11. The error is:

> Cannot invoke initializer for PhoneData with an argument list of type '(phoneName: String)'

The struct was working in my last app with same format but this one is not working?

```
import UIKit

struct PhoneData {
    var phoneName:String!
    var phoneColor:String!
    var phonePrice:String!
    var phoneImage:UIImage!
}

class PhoneTableVC: UITableViewController {
    var arrayOfPhoneData = [PhoneData]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        arrayOfPhoneData = [PhoneData(phoneName: "IPHONE X",phoneColor: "Blue",phonePrice: "1000",phoneImage: Image Literal)]
    }
}
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the actual, exact, and complete error message. Don't type it in. Copy and paste it.

Comment: Your code is OK and should compile, provided that you supply proper `UIImage` instance for `phoneImage`.

Comment: yah it did the error was weird because when i closed and then opened Xcode the error was gone it must be a bug but my Xcode is not beta